# Magento EE : optionsPrice.formatPrice is not working correctly

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14

I am getting issue with magento format price by JS. This is not rounding correctly.

For example: A product has price $69.95 and catalog rule also applied on this. New special price comes after applied price rule is  54.955.

Now when i format this new special price using `optionsPrice.formatPrice(54.555)`. It returns $54.55 instead $54.56.

When I changed the value 54.556 or 54.5555, It is rounding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue after 5 hour digging the code. Issue has fixed by override `formatCurrency` method in file `js/varien/js.js`. Changes are given below :

**File** : `js/varien/js.js`

**Add following line :**

```
price = price*100;
price = Math.round(price.toPrecision(10))/100;
```

**Before :**

```
var i = parseInt(price = Math.abs(+price || 0).toFixed(precision)) + "";
```